# How to show some selected value of dropdownlist

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Thymeleaf View

```
 <option th:each="technology:${technology}"
  th:value="${technology}"                                     
  th:selected="${technology==project.getTechnology()}"
  th:text="${technology}"/>
```

Java Controller

model.addAttribute("technology",organization.getTechnology());

Answer (score 2):

assuming that you are binding your domain as `myobject` in your controller which also have `technology` as an attribute. Then add  `th:field="*{technology}"`  your code will look like below
 in controller

```
model.addAttribute("technology",organization.getTechnology());
model.addAttribute("myobject",new MyClass());
```

```html
<form th:object="${myobject}">
 <select class="selectpicker"
        id="tech"                                 
        th:field="*{technology}"> 
        <option th:each="technology:${technology}" 
            th:value="${technology}" th:text="${technology}">
        </option></select>
<form>
```